# Create a dedicated memcache for all the deployments

Tags: azure, memcached

I am trying to setup a cloud service of n dedicated roles acting as a dedicated cache (https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/#getting-started-cache-role-instance).

I would like to have a single cloud service providing memcache to all other roles (in other cloud services). Looking to Microsoft's samples, I only can find cloud service deployments with some dedicated cache roles (config with autodiscover=true).

Is it possible to have just a single cloud service providing the feature to the other services?

Anyone can show me a sample (just how to configure security for the host & clients)

Thanks

Comment: The last time I asked about this, which was maybe a year ago, there wasn't an easy way to get communication between multiple Cloud Services. It might be possible using a Virtual Network, but I haven't looked into it. The other alternative is to use Azure Shared Cache, which costs money but pretty much Just Works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached Microsoft and they told to me: this is not possible at the moment (without custom solutions). The current cache only works with the self deployment. More info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh914161#Concept_CacheClusters

Good news, will be possible in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SASL for auth - https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol.

Comment: I would like to have a regular dedicated deployment without introducing new dependencies.